# Most frequent value using pandas.DataFrame.resample

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am using `pandas.DataFrame.resample` to resample a grouped Pandas `dataframe` with a timestamp index.

In one of the columns, I would like to resample such that I select the most frequent value. At the moment, I am only having success using NumPy functions like `np.max` or `np.sum` etc.

```
#generate test dataframe
data = np.random.randint(0,10,(366,2))
index = pd.date_range(start=pd.Timestamp('1-Dec-2012'), periods=366, unit='D')
test = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

#generate group array
group =  np.random.randint(0,2,(366,))

#define how dictionary for resample
how_dict = {0: np.max, 1: np.min}

#perform grouping and resample
test.groupby(group).resample('48 h',how=how_dict)
```

The previous code works because I have used NumPy functions. However, if I want to use resample by most frequent value, I am not sure. I try defining a custom function like

```
def frequent(x):
    (value, counts) = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
    return value[counts.argmax()]
```

However, if I now do:

```
how_dict = {0: np.max, 1: frequent}
```

I get an empty dataframe...

```
df = test.groupby(group).resample('48 h',how=how_dict)
df.shape
```

Comment: Might help to show desired output, also would be better to shrink sample dataframe to as few rows as possible.  Note also that resample has changed for version 0.18.0 although old syntax still works (but with a warning).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your resample period is too short, so when a group is empty on a period, your user function raise a ValueError not kindly caught by pandas .

But it works without empty groups, for example with regular groups:

```
In [8]: test.groupby(arange(366)%2).resample('48h',how=how_dict).head()
Out[8]: 
              0  1
0 2012-12-01  4  8
  2012-12-03  0  3
  2012-12-05  9  5
  2012-12-07  3  4
  2012-12-09  7  3
```

Or with bigger periods :

```
In [9]: test.groupby(group).resample('122D',how=how_dict)
Out[9]: 
              0  1
0 2012-12-02  9  0
  2013-04-03  9  0
  2013-08-03  9  6
1 2012-12-01  9  3
  2013-04-02  9  7
  2013-08-02  9  1
```

**EDIT**

A workaround can be to manage the empty case :

```
def frequent(x):
    if len(x)==0 : return -1
    (value, counts) = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
    return value[counts.argmax()]
```

For

```
In [11]: test.groupby(group).resample('48h',how=how_dict).head()
Out[11]: 
               0  1
0 2012-12-01   5  3
  2012-12-03   3  4
  2012-12-05 NaN -1
  2012-12-07   5  0
  2012-12-09   1  4
```

Comment: I see.. thanks! Is it possible to make the custom function work with empty groups?